# How can I specify the type of a dispatch function passed as a prop to a child component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, dispatch

I have a dispatch function called `dispatchFetch` that I need to pass from the parent component to the child component, and as I am using TypeScript, I need to declare the type in the child component.

My parent component contains the following code:

```
<ProductionSchedule 
    dispatchFetch={ dispatchFetch }
/>
```

The child component (`ProductionSchedule`) contains the following:

```
export interface Props {
    dispatchFetch: Dispatch;
};
```

TypeScript throwing the following error: `Type 'Dispatch<Action>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<AnyAction>'.`

Hovering over the prop, in the parent component I can see that the type is `React.Dispatch<Action>`, and in the child component the type is `Dispatch<AnyAction>`.

I have already explicitly set the type in the child to be `<Dispatch>`, and setting it to be `Dispatch<Action>` does not work either. How can I ensure that the types match?

Comment: Why do you need to get dispatch from a prop exactly? Are you working with plain redux or redux toolkit?

Comment: @Kakiz I am working with react-redux

Comment: dispatchFetch: Dispatch<Action>

Comment: @SpencePro Could you elaborate what you mean by "a dispatch function called dispatchFetch" exactly?